# PHP inject into database with PDO & Json

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

similar question I have asked before... But this time with PDO. Trying to understand PDO better, as I know it is better than doing a mysql Query in PHP.

So, I have JSON Data:

```
{
   "serial_number": "70-b3-d5-1a-00-be",
   "dateTime": "2020-08-14 20:58",
   "passReport": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "passList": [
            {
               "passType": 1,
               "time": "20:58:38"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to get it into my sql database with the following code:

```
foreach ($decoded as $item) {
    if ($item->serial_number !== '70-b3-d5-1a-00-be') continue;
        
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable SET serial_number = :serial_number, date_time = :date_time , id = :id, passType = :passType,  time_created = :time_created");
        $statement->execute([
            'serial_number' => $item->serial_number,
            'date_time' => $item->dateTime,
            'id' => $item->passReport->id,
            'passType' => $item->passReport->passList->passType,
            'time_created' => $item->passReport->passList->time
        ]);
}
```

But the problem is, I don't know what the correct syntax is to execute into mysql with PDO.
I am having a hard time figuring out how to reach each array.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field2) VALUES (:value1, :value2, :value3)`

Comment: Note you can `prepare` once and `execute` many times. This makes any loops more efficient.

Comment: PDO queries are still MySQL queries. The term "inject" isn't appropriate here, you're "executing" queries.

Comment: If you're ever wondering how MySQL works [check the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html). The syntax is spelled out in very specific detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick restructuring of this should make it work and be more efficient:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (serial_number, date_time, id, passType, time_created) VALUES (:serial_number, :date_time, :id, :passType, :time_created");

foreach ($decoded as $item) {
    if ($item->serial_number !== '70-b3-d5-1a-00-be') continue;

    $statement->execute([
        'serial_number' => $item->serial_number,
        'date_time' => $item->dateTime,
        'id' => $item->passReport->id,
        'passType' => $item->passReport->passList->passType,
        'time_created' => $item->passReport->passList->time
    ]);
}
```

It's worth noting having columns with styles like `passType` (camel-case) and `time_created` (underscored) is a real mess. Pick a style and stick to it consistently.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks man. I'll definitely take that advice with the camel-case and underscored. I should fix it. Thanks!